# Scribe - restore access token with code (OAuth2 vs OAuth1)

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, scribe

In an OAuth1 process, I save my token and my secret and recreate my access token like the following:

```
 accessToken = new Token(token, secret);
```

In an OAuth2 process, I only get a code. If I save this code and try to recreate the access token like following, the app crashes:

```
Verifier v = new Verifier(code);
accessToken = service.getAccessToken(null, v);
```

The response:

> org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Cannot extract an acces token. Response was: {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No matching code found."}

**How do I recreate an access token in an OAuth2 process?**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is not with your Java code to extract the token (the bit that you're showing at least) - that looks fine from what I can tell.

The error message is a response back from the service you're trying to authorize with (e.g. twitter, or whatever it is in your case) saying that

```
code
```

is not known. That could happen if too much time has passed since you got that authorization code from the service, or simply that the authorization code you have is wrong for some reason.

In order to provide proper answer, I'd need to see a bit more code... how precisely are you getting the value of

```
code
```

that is going into the constructor of

```
Verifier
```

? Please can you provide more of the code you're using for that?

[Sorry, I would have added this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation.]